# solving linear ODE with Laplace transformation

Tags: differential-equations

I'm trying to solve a linear ODE with Laplace transformation.

Here is my code :

```
EqDiff = m*D[x[t], {t, 2}] + c*D[x[t], t] + k*x[t] == f[t]
f[t_] := HeavisideTheta[t] - HeavisideTheta[t - \[Tau]]
(EqLaplace = LaplaceTransform[EqDiff, t, s] /. {x[0] -> 0, 
 x'[0] -> 0}) // TraditionalForm
SolLapX = Solve[EqLaplace, LaplaceTransform[x[t], t, s]]
SolTemx =  InverseLaplaceTransform[SolLapX[[1, 1, 2]], s, t] /. {m -> 1, c -> 2, k -> 3, \[Tau] -> 1}
x[t_] := SolTemx
Plot[x, {t, 0, 10}]
```

I didn't obtain a plot with Plot function.
I suppose that it is due to the fact that the result from the InversLaplaceTransform function is not simplifier and can be analysed as a complex.

Do you have some ideas so as to simplify the result obtained with the InversLaplaceTransform so that i can obtain the plot.

I tried FullSimplify but it didn't work.

Comment: Try plotting x[t], since that is what you have defined, or Re[x[t]] if necessary

Comment: perfect it works. The only issue is that the plot has some blanks... Some parts of the plot are not plotted, it is like i have some display problems. Do you have an ideas of the cause ?

Comment: but, with the real part the plot is perfect, it may come from numerical approximations

Comment: See my answer.  With the ComplexExpand and FullSimplify, you don't even need the Re.  The blanks go away also

Answer (score 1):

```
EqDiff = m*D[x[t], {t, 2}] + c*D[x[t], t] + k*x[t] == f[t];
f[t_] := HeavisideTheta[t] - HeavisideTheta[t - \[Tau]];
(EqLaplace = LaplaceTransform[EqDiff, t, s] /. {x[0] -> 0, x'[0] -> 0});
SolLapX = Solve[EqLaplace, LaplaceTransform[x[t], t, s]];
SolTemx = InverseLaplaceTransform[SolLapX[[1, 1, 2]], s, t] /. {m -> 1, c -> 2, k -> 3, \[Tau] -> 1};
x[t_] = SolTemx // ComplexExpand // FullSimplify;
Plot[Evaluate[x[t]], {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

Comment: great, thank you ! the only point that i didn't understant is why have you used the Evaluate function since you define x[t_]= and not x[t_]:= and consequently the function has already been evaluated

Comment: Evaluate often speeds up plotting, but in this case the plot is simple enough to not notice the difference.